# When does SQL Server do an index seek vs index scan?

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

What are the criteria that determine if SQL Server chooses to perform an `index seek` instead of an `index scan`?

I have a large table with a `datetime2` column (and a non clustered index on that column).

My query contains this `where` condition

```
WHERE TIALETTURETAG_Data >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND TIALETTURETAG_Data <= '2021-12-31 23:59:59'`
```

Looking at the execution plan, SQL Server performs an index scan, is there a way to change its behaviour to make it execute an index seek that is much faster?

And why did it decide to perform an index scan?

**NB:** selecting only this fields (the primary key and the field where the condition is applied

```
SELECT 
    [TIALETTURETAG_Id], [TIALETTURETAG_Data] 
FROM 
    TIALETTURETAG 
WHERE 
    TIALETTURETAG_Data >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
    AND TIALETTURETAG_Data <= '2021-12-31 23:59:59'
```

SQL Server performs an index seek.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]
(
    [TIALETTURETAG_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdLettura] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdSessione] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Tag] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_TagOld] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceUtenza] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Data] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Posizione] [geography] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Cap] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceOds] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Targa] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Tipo] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_TipoTag] [char](1) NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_TipoSegnalazione] [smallint] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_TipoEvento] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_SegnalazioneNote] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Extra] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdOds] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdDettOds] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdAuto] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Stato] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Rifiuto] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Peso] [numeric](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Volume] [numeric](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Matricola] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Nota] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Ranking] [tinyint] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IdFile] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_MacAddress] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_IMEI] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_UsrAPI] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_SNBlackBox] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Insert_Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Insert_Data] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Update_Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Update_Data] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Versione] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_GisUtenza] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Indirizzo] [int] NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_Sessione] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceAccesso] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TIALETTURETAG] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TIALETTURETAG_Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_IdLettura]   
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_IdLettura]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Tag]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Tag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_TagOld]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_TagOld]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_CodiceUtenza]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceUtenza]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Data]  
        DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Data]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Cap]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Cap]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_CodiceOds]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceOds]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Targa]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Targa]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Tipo]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Tipo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_TipoEvento]  
        DEFAULT ('L') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_TipoEvento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_SegnalazioneNote]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_SegnalazioneNote]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Extra]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Extra]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Stato]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Stato]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Peso]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Peso]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Volume]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Volume]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Matricola]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Matricola]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Nota]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Nota]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_MacAddress]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_MacAddress]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_IMEI]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_IMEI]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_SNBlackBox]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_SNBlackBox]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Insert_Login]  
        DEFAULT (CASE WHEN LEFT(app_name(), (7)) <> 'ANTHEA_' THEN RIGHT(suser_sname(), (20)) ELSE RTRIM(REPLACE(app_name(), 'ANTHEA_', '')) END) FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Insert_Login]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_RISODS_Insert_Data]  
        DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Insert_Data]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_RISODS_Update_Login]  
        DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Update_Login]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_RISODS_Update_Data]  
        DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Update_Data]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_Sessione]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_Sessione]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAG_CodiceAccesso]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [TIALETTURETAG_CodiceAccesso]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_AUTOMEZZI] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_IdAuto])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AUTOMEZZI] ([AUTOMEZZI_Identificatore])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_AUTOMEZZI]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_COMFILES] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_IdFile])
REFERENCES [dbo].[COMFILES] ([COMFILES_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_COMFILES]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_COMTIPOSEGNALAZIONE] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_TipoSegnalazione])
REFERENCES [dbo].[COMTIPOSEGNALAZIONE] ([COMTIPOSEGNALAZIONE_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_COMTIPOSEGNALAZIONE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_RISODS] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_IdOds])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RISODS] ([RISODS_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_RISODS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_RISRIFCONTRC] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_IdDettOds])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RISRIFCONTRC] ([RISRIFCONTRC_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_RISRIFCONTRC]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAGINDIRIZZI] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_Indirizzo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TIALETTURETAGINDIRIZZI] ([TIALETTURETAGINDIRIZZI_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAGINDIRIZZI]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAGUTENZE] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_GisUtenza])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TIALETTURETAGUTENZE] ([TIALETTURETAGUTENZE_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIALETTURETAGUTENZE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIATIPOTAG] FOREIGN KEY([TIALETTURETAG_TipoTag])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TIATIPOTAG] ([TIATIPOTAG_Codice])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TIALETTURETAG_TIATIPOTAG]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_TIALETTURETAG_Tag] CHECK  ((case when [TIALETTURETAG_TipoEvento]='L' AND len([TIALETTURETAG_Tag])>(0) OR [TIALETTURETAG_TipoEvento]<>'L' then (1) else (0) end=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_TIALETTURETAG_Tag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_TIALETTURETAG_Tipo] CHECK  (([TIALETTURETAG_Tipo]='B' OR [TIALETTURETAG_Tipo]='C'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TIALETTURETAG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_TIALETTURETAG_Tipo]
GO
```

Comment: The SQL Server **cost-based optimizer** looks at your whole query - if you do e.g. a `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table ......` then chances are very slim that it'll use an index seek - since after finding any matching values, SQL Server would have to do very expensive **key lookups** to get the rest of the columns. With just the `WHERE` clause, no complete table structure, and no information about the data stored in that table, it's **impossible** to know what's going on.

Comment: One thing you could try: do a `SELECT TIALETTURETAG_Data FROM dbo.YourTable` with the above `WHERE` condition - do you get an index seek now? How many rows are in the table in total - how many of those will be selected by that condition?

Comment: I don't understand: how can you have an index seek on `TIALETTURETAG_Data` if you have no index on it? Or do you have an index but haven't shown it? You likely need to add `INCLUDE` columns to such an index, in order to cover the query

Comment: Side note - unless it's your intention to ignore events that happen during the last second of the year, it's almost always simpler to work with time periods with an inclusive start point and an *exclusive* end point. E.g. prefer `TIALETTURETAG_Data < '20220101'` over `TIALETTURETAG_Data <= '2021-12-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: Aside... an index on both sides of a foreign key constraint is usually useful and recommended, i.e.: not just the primary keys on the referenced table/s. Ref: [Indexes on Foreign Key Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints).